# How can I show the data read from the influxdb?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the response of an influxdb query, but I don't know how to show the response values. I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

I'm trying with this code, but it doesn't work. I just want to show the values of data.

```
      public async Task  ConsultaBD()
     {
        var influxDbClient = new InfluxDbClient("http://host:8086/", "***", "****", InfluxDbVersion.v_1_3);
        var query = "SELECT * FROM TFA WHERE time >= '2019-05-21' and time < '2019-05-22' ";
        var response = await influxDbClient.Client.QueryAsync(query, "dbname");

        var x = response.ToString();
        return(x);
     }
```

This is returned string with this code:

```
      "System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [InfluxData.Net.InfluxDb.Models.Responses.Serie]"
```

Comment: `ToString` method by default returns the fully qualified name of the type which  "System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [InfluxData.Net.InfluxDb.Models.Responses.Serie]" in this case. You need to go through that list and concatenate values to one string if you want to return one string.

Comment: Besides that, in order to return a string from an async method, it must be declared as `public async Task<string> ConsultaBD()`.

Comment: @Iker: What values does your `SELECT * FROM TFA` returns, i.e. what columns does the `TFA` table contain?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
public async Task<string> ConsultaBD()
{
   var influxDbClient = new InfluxDbClient("http://host:8086/", "***", "****", InfluxDbVersion.v_1_3);
   var query = "SELECT * FROM TFA WHERE time >= '2019-05-21' and time < '2019-05-22' ";
   var response = await influxDbClient.Client.QueryAsync(query, "dbname");

   string x = "";
   foreach(var item in response.Values)
   {
      x += item.toString(); // You could add + ", " to separate them appropriately
   }
   return x;
}
```

Or a little simpler:

```
return string.Join(",", response.Values.Select(v => v.ToString()));
```

However I don't know in which format the objects of the Values list are. So maybe you'll need item. and then a different property.